# .NET Geometry library

Tags: c#, geometry

I'm starting a new project in .NET which will require some geometry algorithms, such as:

- checking if a point is inside a polygon
- bezier curves
- line intersections, etc.

I've found some libraries, however, they are paid/expensive, these include:

- G# - http://www.ceometric.com/store.html
- DigitalRune Geometry - http://www.digitalrune.com/Products/Geometry/Overview.aspx
- NLIB - http://www.smlib.com/nlib.html
- sgCore - http://www.geometros.com/sgcore/index.htm

These do what I need and much more, which makes me spend too much money on something that won't get used so much.

I've found some open source projects:

- [MATH.NET](http://www.mathdotnet.com/)
- [alglib](http://www.alglib.net/)
- anti-grain ([C# bindings/port](http://sourceforge.net/projects/agg-sharp/))

But these do less than I need, however, they're easy to find when you look on google. After some time searching, I've found this library:

- **Tektosyne** (http://www.kynosarges.de/Tektosyne.html)

Which does most of what I need. It is also free of charge and is provided "AS-IS". Which is good.

However, if you search google for "Tektosyne", you find very few results. So my question is (for those who have experience with some "advanced" usage of geometries in c# of StackOverflow):

***Do you have another libraries to recommend or why is this library not "popular"?***

Comment: Why ask why the library is not "popular" when you can ask for recommendations of a good library that will fit your requirements?

Answer (score 9):

Have you looked at this?
 [github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial](https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial)

Or

NetTopologySuite https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite

Comment: http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/ does not lives anymore. Use this instead https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're looking for something for WinForms.  If you haven't looked into WPF yet, the functionality that you mentioned is all available there.  Plus you could always host a WPF Control in a WinForms program.

Comment: Winforms too, GraphicsPath class.

Answer (score 1):

We are using sgCore in our 3D programs. Beautiful library. We are purchased full sourcescodes - very clear code inside.